# Where can I download a digital Starcraft II copy?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have already bought SC2, and now my copy of the game is not with me. I would like to download it from an official website, but I failed to find the link.

Where can I find the game on an official site?

(If it matters, I bought the EU game)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download it directly from your Battle.Net account.

https://eu.battle.net/account/management/download/#sc2-downloads

Click on the Windows or Mac button to download.

(You can even change the language if you want. I bought the French version but was able to download and play with the English version.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [www.battle.net](http://www.battle.net) and login with your Battle.net account, You should be able to re-download from there.

Under My Games, just click on the SC II boxart, and select Manage Game. There should be a download link.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your account at [www.battle.net](http://www.battle.net) and go to "Account -> Your Game Accounts -> Starcraft II".  There, you will find "Download Game Client"